# Protocol errors with Amazon Redshift database. "ERROR: Invalid protocol sequence 'P' while in PortalSuspended state."

Tags: java, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum, jdbi3

I Am trying to run select * from table_name limit 500000, but it returns this error in java

```
Protocol errors with Amazon Redshift database. "ERROR: Invalid protocol sequence 'P' while in PortalSuspended state."
```

Redshift driver: redshift-driver-2.1.0.9.jar
Redshift engine cluster version: 1.0.49780

[DB result for select version; in Redshift database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/datMV.png)

Could you please help me, why getting protocol errors in the Redshift database